# WPF Browser Application Installing as Non-Admin user + .NET Framework

Tags: wpf, xbap

My app uses .net 4 Client Profile, and needs to be installed on a machine, which doesn't have the net framework and by a non-admin user. Could anyone confirm if it's possible?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to enable your application to be deployed via [ClickOnce](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t71a733d%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

Comment: Done that - but non-admin users still can't install it. As it attempts to install .net fwk and fails due the lack of right. Out of interest can you install WEBBrowserAppplication as anything bar Click Once App?